# about the model design in mvvm

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, windows-phone, mvvm-light

While I'm learning the MVVM, I saw a online course in Microsoft Virtual Academy, 
Ben Riga wrote codes below. What I wonder is the questions below:

What are the benefits of using an Interface named IDataService? Get the data in a method of the model class or in the viewmodel class would be result in less codes. There must be some future benefits that I can't figure out. Can somebody explain it for me?

**Model:**

```
public class CommonDataItem
{
    public DataItem(string uid)
    {
        Uid = uid;
    }
    public string Uid
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
// Other properties ...
}

public interface IDataService
{
    void GetItem(Action<CommonDataItem> callback, 
        string uid);
}

public class DataService : IDataService
{
    public void GetItem(Action<CommonDataItem>
        callback, string uid)
    {
        // Retrieve the data from the actual source
        // ...
        var item = new DataItem(...);
        callback(item);
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IDataService _dataService;
    public const string Title_PropertyName = "Title";
    private string _title = string.Empty;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set
        {
            if (_title == value)
            return;
            _title = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(Title_PropertyName);
        }
    }

    // Constructor...
    public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
        _dataService.GetData(
            (item) =>
            {
                Title = item.Title;
                });
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all as usual in **MVVM** you do not have to do something, it is a recommendation or best practice. In general you are free to code the data access into your view model - and to do so might be a good practice for small projects or prototypical implementations.

However, you should consider that this also has some drawbacks. The reason for implementing a data service is that this component is reusable and even might be usable in other scenarios like an MVC application. Furthermore, it separates out the concern of getting model from a data store.

The reason for implementing an IDataService is that you can exchange the implementation when you need to, e.g. for supplying design time data. When you need this, you also have to consider the inversion of control pattern that heavily relies on interfaces. In this case also a IOC container might be interesting, although not necessary.

But, first of all the above are recommendations, patterns, design guidelines, and best practices that give you the freedom to design an application that best fits your requirements.

**Edit: size of the data service**

The design and scope of your data service depends on your application and it's requirements. It can range from a single data service for all you models to one data service per model. Furthermore, the design of you data service interfaces may be a separate decision. One service class can implement several service interfaces, thus allowing for hiding certain aspects (methods) of the implementation from the user.

When designing a data service you should look into the unit of work and repository patterns. There are several sample implementations around.

If you just need a very simple unit of work pattern that is based on a single query you can have a look at my blog, where I wrote about turning an **IQueryable** into a unit of work pattern. However, this fits only very simple cases, generally a complete implementation with a repository and a proper unit of work item is more advisably.

Comment: It would be great if "have a look at my blog, where I wrote about turning an IQueryable into a unit of work pattern" linked to your blog post Jignesh. What's the URL?

Comment: actually I dont have any blog

Answer (score 0):

I think the goal of IDataService is just like a typical Interface : to create a layer which separate the definitions and the implemations so you can change the DataService class if needed and don't need to change the logic use it.